# how to make Tests on React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing

I'm coding with react native for a university project 
I need to make Unit tests in the same way that java use JUnit

what can I use to do so ?

I'm using expo to see if my application is working but my teacher wants real unit test

tank you for your help :)

Comment: Check this, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native

Comment: I check , the link you gave me didn't work for me but after searching on internet I found something , thank you

Comment: It's a Jest "search about it :D", can u share with me what you found cuz I'm interested too

Comment: at the end I found this page because I'm using expo, check this , https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/testing-with-jest/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use expo :(